# d3.js equivalent to $(this)

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I would like to modify the state of a text node when it is clicked upon, but apparently i fail to access it correctly. When i click, nothing happens (unless i use the jquery selector, and not all command work).
So my question is: what is the d3.js equivalent to $(this) ?

```
var buttons = svg.selectAll(".button");
buttons.on("click",function(d){
    var target = $(this).attr('target');
    var visible  = $(this).attr('visible');
    if(visible==='1'){
        svg.selectAll(".bar."+target)
                .transition()
                .duration(500)
                .ease("elastic")
                .style('display','none');
    $(this).attr('visible','0')
                .style('text-decoration','line-through');
    }else{
        svg.selectAll(".bar."+target)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(500)
                    .ease("elastic")
                    .style('display','inline');
        $(this).attr('visible','1');
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out `d3.select(this)` is the correct answer.

Code now is :

```
var buttons = svg.selectAll(".button");
buttons.on("click",function(d){
    var target = $(this).attr('target');
    var visible  = $(this).attr('visible');
    if(visible==='1'){
        svg.selectAll(".bar."+target).transition().duration(500).ease("elastic").style('display','none');
        d3.select(this).attr('visible','0').style('text-decoration','line-through');


    }else{
        svg.selectAll(".bar."+target).transition().duration(500).ease("elastic").style('display','inline');
        d3.select(this).attr('visible','1').style('text-decoration','');
    }
});
```